# Connect to a server in a Docker container

Tags: docker, server, dockerfile, backend

I've written a web backend in Rust (even though I don't think it's relevant). The server application works perfectly outside of a Docker container. However, when I tried to put it inside the container, it doesn't work anymore. I've made sure that I exposed the port I'm using and also mapped it to the corresponding port outside of the container. I've also made sure that I fetch from 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 from the frontend. Why is the server still not working? Below is some more concrete information:

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rust:latest
WORKDIR /backend/

COPY src/ /backend/src
COPY Cargo.toml /backend/

RUN cargo build
CMD ["cargo", "run"]
EXPOSE 3003
```

The command I entered into the terminal:

```
docker run -it -p 3003:3003 backend
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I fetch from 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 from the frontend"?  I think the problem is in the frontend because with this setup you should be able to invoke port 3003 directly from your browser.  Have you tried?

Comment: I used the fetch API in the frontend to fetch from port 3003. What do you mean by saying "to invoke port 3003"?

Comment: maybe you could try the ip in ipconfig like 192.168.x.x:3003 instead of 127.0.0.1:3003?

Comment: @Pino I haven't tried yet. However, why does it not work in a container?

Comment: Using "0.0.0.0" makes sense on the server side (in this case your backend) when you start the server, not on the client side (in this case your frontend).  It is not related to containers.

Comment: I changed 0.0.0.0 to localhost and it doesn't even work outside the container.

Comment: After trying again, `localhost` worked outside the container, but still not inside the container.

Comment: What is the exact URL you're trying to connect to from the host, and what error are you getting?  In your code you're setting up a network listener of some sort; what address and port are you listening on or binding to?  The Dockerfile and `docker run` command in the question seem fine to me.

Comment: The URL is simply 0.0.0.0:3003 (or localhost:3003 / 127.0.0.1:3003 as I've tried.) I currently bind my server program to 127.0.0.1:3003.